Can I use rear (thru) axle with crack for a few rides, before getting a new one?
Can I use rear (thru) axle with crack for a few rides, before getting a new one ?
The photo is below.
I'm think to order from Aliexpress (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33047306345.html), at the local bishop it costs from 80$.
Also, I bit curious, why thru axle are so expensive ?
Does AlieExpress Item has acceptable quality ?
Can I use this axle for a few times before the new one arrives?
My axle with a crack:

AliExpress Item:

UPDATE:
Finally I about an axle at LBS made by KCNC "brand" for 45$.


How much do you value the integrity of your bones?

However, thru axles should normally cost less than 80 USD. Maybe half. But if you have some special type, it may be worse. You need the right dimension, threading, tapering...

You are comparing two extremes: there's a middle ground, specialized online shop approved by components manufacturers (important aspect for warranty claims) that are quite discounted compared to the official RRP (usually followed by LBS) but for original parts - (80€ us super high though, RRP for some DT Swiss or Shimano axles is 40€).

@Rеnаud In which country only special approved shops offer a valid warranty?

@VladimirFГероямслава well, a bit more complicated than that, as you have seller warranty and manufacturer warranty. Legally, there's a 2 years seller warranty (EU) and if there's a defect, the seller can provide you with an "alternative product", but if manufacturers offers additional warranty beyond the terms of the seller warranty, they can reject a claim if the item comes for a non-approved shop.

If you're gonna go with AliExpress, at least grab a name brand item from ZTTO or the like. Not some generic version with absolutely zero quality control.

Tell us how it went! If we don't hear from you, we'll assume the worst ;-).

You'll be absolutely fine up till the moment it fails.
The problem is, when will it fail? It could go immediately as you tighten down the lever, which is good because your ride hasn't even started.
Or it could go at any time on your ride.  The exact moment of failure cannot be predicted.  You might get a whole ride in; no one can predict.
But when the axle does let go, the unthreaded side will loosen and possibly eject itself from the bike. This leaves one dropout unsupported, and your wheel will cant sideways to start rubbing on the frame, or the wheel will bind on the frame and lock up completely.
If this is your rear wheel, you'll do a surprise skid and possibly be okay as long as you're going in a straight line, and its dry, and no one is behind you, and so on.
If this is your front wheel, you'll likely go "over the bars" as the bike stops but you don't.   Not a good place to be.

Recommendation:
Don't ride that bike.   You can walk, bus, train, uber, taxi, carpool, drive, or work from home instead.
Buy a quality through axle from a local bike shop.   Sure it will cost more, but you're mobile again immediately.
If AE is all you can afford, then avoid using the bike until an un-cracked axle is fitted.

Aliexpress is great for some types of bike parts.  But axles are safety-critical and saving some money in the short term is the definition of short-term gain, long-term loss. Based on Aliexpress and DX items I've personally bought and ridden:
Chains: NO not worth the cost savings - decreased life, some were stretched out of the box, and one only lasted 100 km before failing.
Cassettes: YES there's not a lot in a cassette to go wrong.  Worth it, though you may need to keep your previous lockring and spacers.
Chainrings: NO Aluminium chainrings lasted me about a week before failing.
Lights:  MAYBE Some lights are great, some are rubbish.   Most of the integrated batteries lose capacity and have half the runtime after 6 months usage, presuming they survive the rain.
Brake pads/parts:  ABSOLUTELY NOT Brakes are safety critical. Don't risk it. Same goes for stems, frames, handlebars, seatposts.
Saddles:  MAYBE This is one item I've never bought from AE.
Reflectors:  YES Spoke reflectors work well; recommended. As does DOT tape.
Cleats:  YES mostly they're shaped plastic; hard to get that wrong unless the tolerances are off.
Tubes and tyres:  MAYBE Its a mixed bag - some are great and some aren't.
Shoes:  NO  Fit and comfort is critical.  You can't test them or try them on beforehand.
Clothes, gloves, bibs, etc:  YES  Just remember Chinese sizing is small and often short.  I frequently have to tailor new clothes for a better fit, but the price is worth it.
Brand-name stuff:  MAYBE  It's never authentic brand name. At best it is third-shift, or rejects. If the price is right perhaps, but not without significant savings.

Thank you, especially for the list of Do and Don't, I think it will be interesting to other riders also.

I wish I had read that list earlier!! After a while of excitedly buying cheap Shimano drivetrain parts from Aliexpress I stopped thinking and bought a 12-pack of no-name disk brake pads because they were so much cheaper. I crashed hard when the braking surface simply sheared of the pad! I learned my lesson the hard way... (of course the seller no longer exists).

I agree with the point about Aliexpress... but would extend it to any other "out-of-jurisdiction" seller. Don't buy safety-critical stuff from anybody against whom a damages claim could not be enforced, and don't assume that just because something appears to carry a well-known brand that it's not counterfeit.

Thru-axles are expensive because they are safety critical and they also take more load than almost any other part of the bike. Axles are important, depending on the weight distribution of the bike, gear, and rider, either axle might be taking something like 80% of the total weight of the bike+rider+gear, and that’s on perfectly smooth and level tarmac. And any kind of hard landing will transmit all the force involved through the axle as well, which may be many times what it normally has to support. So they need to be really strong. And the combination of being safety critical and needing to be really strong means that QA is important, and good QA is expensive.
That said, USD 80 for a thru-axle is absurd unless you’re looking at a top-of-the-line version of a specialist part, and even then I would not expect it to cost quite that much. Either that LBS is up-charging to a huge degree, or you have a more expensive bike than would ever be expected for somebody who is ordering parts from AliExpress.
Additionally though, this is never something I would buy online unless either ordering direct from the manufacturer, or ordering direct from a dedicated bike-parts retailer that I actively trust. Amazon, AliExpress, and most other online marketplace type sellers are known to mix stock, and are known to have plenty of scummy sellers who are trying to shift stuff that ranges from being useless, to dangerous, to possibly outright illegal in some places. The cost of any issue that arises from getting a sub-par part here is going to be so so much more than what is saved that the risk is just not worth it unless there is truly no other option.
As far as what you have, riding that is a serious gamble at best. Best case scenario, it fails as you tighten things up. Worst case it fails in the middle of the ride. If that happens on the back you may be fine, but you may not. If it happens on the front you’re dealing with one of the most dangerous failure modes possible for a bicycle short of the frame falling apart.

just a minor, note: for "old bikes" with open-ended fork the axle + QR are almost 5 times cheaper.
